# NSKeyedArchiver crashing my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

For some reason, the following NSData lines are causing my app to crash. Here's the error that the console throws me:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteAttributedString initWithString:: nil value' ***

Does anyone know why this might be? I'm using XCode 5, and I didn't seem to have this problem when building in XCode 4. Is there an alternative string of code that will correct this problem? If I remove these lines, the crash does not occur. However, I need to save my data, haha.

```
    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:strainsfinal];
```

---

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)arrayUpdated
{
    Strains = appdelegate.strainsfinal;
    [StrainTableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"notification received");
}


- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableview
{
    return 1;
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } else {
        return [Strains count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *strainTableIdentifier = @"StrainTableCell";

    StrainTableCell *cell = (StrainTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)


        cell = [[StrainTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:strainTableIdentifier];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;



    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StrainTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"Using the search results");

        cell.titleLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

        NSLog(@"%@", searchResults);



    } else {
        NSLog(@"Using the FULL LIST!!");
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Description"];
        cell.ratingLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Rating"];
        cell.ailmentLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ailment"];
        cell.actionLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Action"];
        cell.ingestLabel.text = [[Strains objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ingestion"];

    }
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    strainsfinal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *dataSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"strains"];
    if (dataSave != Nil) {
        Strains = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];
        // strainsfinal = [Strains copy];
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urlhere.com/file.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    bool firstlaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstlaunch"];
    if (firstlaunch != YES) {



        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"arthritisswitch"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"cancerswitch"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hivswitch"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"insomniaswitch"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"migrainesswitch"];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstlaunch"];

    }



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData
{
    [data appendData:theData];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    NSData *dataSave = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"strains"];
    NSMutableArray *oldStrains = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataSave];

    NSMutableSet *blankArray = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

    // Strains = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    Strains = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    if (oldStrains.count < Strains.count) {
        for (int x = oldStrains.count - 1; x < Strains.count; x++) {
            [oldStrains addObject:[Strains objectAtIndex:x]];
        }

    }
    if (Strains.count > 0) {


        blankArray = [Strains copy];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = nil;

        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Title"
                                                     ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        Strains = [[blankArray allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        int count = 0;
        for (NSDictionary *item in Strains) {
            [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:@"position"];
            if ([item valueForKey:@"checked"] ==  nil) {
                bool checked = NO;
                [item setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:checked]  forKey:@"checked"];
            }
            count++;
        }

        dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Strains];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"strains"];
        [strainsfinal addObjectsFromArray:Strains];
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure that you're connected to 3G or Wi-Fi." delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;


}


-(void)updateStrains:(NSDictionary *)item
{
    /*
     NSLog(@"updating items");
     NSNumber *position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[item objectForKey:@"position"] intValue]];
     NSIndexPath *itemIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[position intValue] inSection:0];
     NSLog(@"%@",itemIndex);
     [strainsfinal replaceObjectAtIndex:itemIndex.row withObject:item];
     */

    NSData *dataSave = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:strainsfinal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dataSave forKey:@"strains"];
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"arrayupdated" object:self userInfo:nil];


}
```

Comment: No, not "the following lines."  One line is causing your app to crash.  Do you know which one it is?  I bet it is not here, actually.  Here the problem is that `dataSave` is probably `nil`.  After that you try to get it later, and when you try to make a string out of one of the values you get that error because it is `nil`.  Check on that.

Comment: @borrrden Correction, the NSData *dataSave line is crashing it (according to my breakpoints).

Comment: That error message doesn't make sense for that line, but really make sure that it is not `nil`.  What is `strainsFinal` anyway?  Maybe *that* is `nil`.  Somewhere something is `nil` where it shouldn't be.

Comment: The issue is most likely in the `encodeWithCoder:` implementation of whatever `strainsfinal` is. But it seems to me that an issue with an `init` method would be during unarchiving, not archiving.

Comment: @borrrden Pardon my ignorance, but what does 'nil' mean exactly? strainsFinal is a mutable array of favorited items (selected from a tableview).

Comment: @borrrden Just published the stack above. Take a look... Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Based on the stack trace you appear to be trying to archive an array that ultimately contains `UITableViewCell` instances. Why are you trying to archive table cells? Shouldn't you archive the data used to generate the cells?

Comment: Um, if you don't know what `nil` is than I'm afraid that you have a more urgent problem.  You should take a moment to learn what it is, but it is the same as `null` in other languages.  It means "contains no value".  Also, what @rmaddy said is correct.  You should archive your items from the array of data objects, but you are archiving the actual table view cell objects (so it seems).

Comment: @rmaddy Ahh I see. Didn't realize I was taking the whole cell rather than just the data inside of it. So what would my code look like if I wanted to archive the single objects inside of the cell? As for nil, I figured it meant 0. Was just an assumption though, lol.

Comment: There is no "object inside of the cell".  There is a data source, and cells that are generated based on that data source (i.e. `tableView.dataSource = X;`).  Archive the objects inside of the data source, you only need the table view to determine which indices are selected.

Comment: @BrittanyL Yes, `nil` ultimately is `0`. You don't archive data inside the cell. You archive the data used by your table's data source.

Comment: @rmaddy Ahhhhh I get it. It's like someone just turned the lights on. I'm using storyboard to create the app. So if my dataSource is set to TableView, what would that line of code look like? Hope I worded that right.

Comment: @BrittanyL No. In the `tableView:numberOfRowsForSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods (and others) you access one or more data structures to populate the table. It is those data structures that must be archived.

Comment: @rmaddy See my TableView code above. "Strains" is undoubtedly my data source. I'm just confused about what I need to change in my NSData line in order to make it all "work"? I don't get why it's archiving the whole cell?

Comment: You need to show how you populate `appDelegate.strainsFinal`.

Comment: @rmaddy See my app delegate above. Removed the stack trace, as the question was getting overloaded. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: You still haven't posted any code that populates `strainsFinal`. The new code simply creates an empty array. Show the code that actually populates `strainsFinal`.

Comment: your approach of using keyed archiever is wrong

Comment: @DivineDesert So what should I be using...?

Comment: @rmaddy strainsFinal *should* be an array of updated favourites. So is this error telling me that strainsFinal is empty? E.g. in my ViewController, I have: -(void)arrayUpdated
{
    Strains = appdelegate.strainsfinal;
    [StrainTableView reloadData];
    
    NSLog(@"notification received");
}